# aurelia js html component

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i am trying to create a customElement, which uses a jquery plugin to create a slideshow. For this plugin, there is no jspm package ofc. I didn't want to create one, because i'm not pretty familiar with jspm.

so i added the js-file and its dependencies to the systemloader and it also gets loaded.

Now i wanted to create a customElement, which has a bind-method that will call the plugin with the custom element. (See my code down there). The problem is, the constructor or the bind method are not invoked at all. Nothing is rendered.

*.js:

```html
import {bindable, customElement, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.bxslider';


@customElement('slider')
export class NewsSlider {
    constructor(element)
    {
        this.elem = element;
    }
    bind() {
        console.log('test');
    }
    @bindable items;
}
```

*.html:

```html
<template>
    <ul class="bxslider" ref="slide">
        <li repeat.for="newsItem of items">
            <div class="slide-container quote" css="background-image: url('/backend/content/${newsItem.Image}'); background-size: cover; height: 650px;">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h2> ${newsItem.Title} </h2>
                    <p> ${newsItem.Content} <p/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</template>
```

Usage:

```html
<template>
    <require from="./slider" />
    <p repeat.for="new of news">
        ${new.Content}
    </p>
<slider items.bind="news"></slider>
</template>
```

Comment: we need the names of the files, not just *.js, to answer this question

Comment: the two upper snippets: slider.js, slider.html

Comment: Check your `config.js` or `package.json`.  What version of aurelia-framework do you have installed?  Is the view that is using the slider element in the same directory as the slider custom element files?  Can you include a screenshot of what the DOM looks like where the slider is supposed to be rendered?  You're missing `@inject(Element)` at the top of the class.  Doubt that is the issue though.